# Internal Server Error when reload in Ionic Angular Universal

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-universal, angular13

The first time it loads without an issue but, when I try to reload routes with query params like this `localhost:4000/u?u=6222d4fd021b3080bc4aa6d4`, it shows me this message.

[image]

This is the error message showed in Google console.

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'".
```

Although I have `Content-Security-Policy` in my `index.html`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:; img-src 'self' data: https:; media-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: sha256-ACotEtBlkqjCUAsddlA/3p2h7Q0iHuDXxk577uNsXwA=; font-src 'self' data: https:; connect-src 'self' wss: https:" />
```

This is the page source of the above page
[image]